# How to add a full edit link to front-end editor?

Tags: plugins, front-end

I would like to add a full edit button to the [Front-end Editor plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/).

It's currently like this:

> [EDIT] Text text text

I would like to make it like:

> [EDIT] Text text text (enables front-end editor)
>
> [FULL EDIT] Text Text Text (goes to the back-end editor)

I think this is the current code for the [EDIT] button:

`wp-content/plugins/front-end-editor/build/editor.min.js`:

```
base.prototype.pre_edit_button = function() {
      var _this = this;
      return jQuery('<button>', {
        'class': 'fee-hover-edit',
        'html': FrontEndEditor.data.edit_text,
        'click': function(ev) {
          _this.last_mouse_pos = ev.pageY;
          return _this.start_editing();
        }
      });
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The plugin works ok? Do you mean: `edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );`?

Comment: Take a look :) http://oi45.tinypic.com/jkf221.jpg

Comment: Although the formatting of your Question could [be improved](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help), I got the idea from the description. What about my questions in the first comment? You seem to be clearly needing [***`edit_post_link`***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link)...

Comment: Does this works for pages, instead of posts? How could I add something like this in that jQuery script? I sux at programming :s

Comment: That's not jQuery, it's PHP and goes within the theme template files. Please, join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7526/advice-to-new-user), eu acho que você precisa de um par de conselhos.

Comment: I'm there, but I need to have 20 rep to talk :s, here's my lame try anyway:

        `}, base.prototype.pre_edit_button = function () {
            var _this = this;
            return jQuery("<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Full Edit',) ?> ", {
            })`

Comment: That's one of the problems, you've been making very low quality Questions, and have gained zero reputation after asking 10 Q's... I've advised this once and goes again: read the [FAQ] and the [ask] page. There's no problem in being a novice programmer, but research and knowledge of the site you can grab at no time.

Comment: Yeah, I've been working 12 hours/day (or more) for the last 7 days, so I'm not in my best moments to think peacefully to write a coese question rsrs, but I'm almost done with my project, finally...

Answer (score 1):

I assume the plugin is a separate thing and does its work by itself.

What you need is to include in your [theme template files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) the default <kbd>Edit</kbd> button.

First off, you need a good code editor. Notepad++, Sublime Text, NetBeans, to cite a few.

Check one of the default WordPress themes, TwentyTen, TwentyEleven or TwentyTwelve. You'll see this: `<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>`. This is the default `Edit` button that you are searching for. Swap to this theme and try to tweak it until you get the idea.

Probably, you'll need some CSS to position it near the plugin's button and to make it visually similar.

***Update***
Just found this excellent Answer by @MikeSchinkel:
[Recommended Books on WordPress for Management and non-Developers?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1557/12615).

Comment: :) I use Notepad++ for html, CSS and SQL files, and NetBeans for PHP, Javascript and pretty much everything else<br/> \n

I know very few about programming, but I've done some amazing things in my project so far, I'm very familiar with wordpress by now... The problem with this script is that the "Edit" button from the plugin doesn't have a static position. It goes up-and-down accompaining the mouse movement, when you hover the content... Meh... i don't know, I think it's simply too hard to do it :s Maybe I should skip this functionality...

Comment: Maybe it's easier to create a button to redirect to the "Page Edit" in back-end? With no specific page id, just like:

wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page

Comment: Well, then you are not so n00b ツ Maybe you can put the PHP default link in a not-fancy fashion, a subtle text like `Edit in backend`...

Comment: Yeah I think I'll do that in last case, but it would be much much better if we could embed it into the javascript ._.